# Microsoft Graph API: Can we read multiple users calendar events using one Microsoft account within an organization or team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-api

I am trying to find a way to read calendar events of my team and can schedule something based on everyone's availability.

I was able to fetch my calendar events successfully. But I am curious if we can get details of calendar events of my colleagues within my team or organization. 
Is there a way we can achieve this? 
If yes, it would be helpful if anyone can share some insights on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you grant the app permissions to read calendars from all users, then you can achieve what you want.

Then, you can get the list of users IDs from `/users`.

Using the IDs, you can retrieve the user calendars. If you only desire the available times in a scheduling assistant way, then you can use the [Find Meeting Times](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes) API also.

Comment: Thanks for your insights on this.

I used the below API and was able to achieve the requirement i was looking for.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"+userId+"/calendarView

Thanks a lot once again!